# Why does tkinter aspect not work in Windows 7?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, windows-7-x64, aspect

I'm trying to write a program that when the root window size is changed, all the widgets and the text within the widgets resizes in proportion. I've used aspect but this does not work in Windows7. Why does tkinter aspect(1,1,1,1) work on Mac & Linux but not in Windows 7

I've run the following snippet of code in Linux and on a Mac and all is fine.

```
from tkinter import *

w = Tk()

w.aspect(1,1,1,1)

w.mainloop()
```

I don't see why it doesn't work in Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: Hum. Never used aspect() before however for resizing I have always used `rowconfigure() / columnconfigure()` for `grid()` or using `fill / expand` for `pack()` Also your example has nothing in the root window and without anything to resize it probably will just be the default window size for tkinter when no widgets are present.

Comment: I imaging you problem is due to windows manager in Windows. Not all options related to WM are available in Windows with Tkinter. Take a look at this post and see if it helps: [Resizing Tkinter Frames with fixed aspect-ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523128/resizing-tkinter-frames-with-fixed-aspect-ratio)

Comment: Thank's Mike, your answer confirms what I was thinking. I was hoping that someone else had had the same issue and had come up with a solution.