# How to create a resizable Frame that mantains aspect ratio in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want a `Frame` in tkinter that resizes and maintains aspect ratio when you resize the tkinter window. I also want it to resize all the contents of the frame by aspect ratio. How can I do this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to remove the user's ability to make the window whatever size is best for them?

Comment: Oh no that's now what I want to do. I want the Frame to resize when the user resizes the window. I don't want to remove the user's ability to resize the window.

Comment: There are options for causing frames and other widgets to resize when their containers change. The specific options are highly specific to your actual needs.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? [resizing-tkinter-frames-with-fixed-aspect-ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523128)

Comment: Well I did see that answer and no it doesn't for me

Comment: ***"no it doesn't for me"***: [Edit] your question and explain in detail **why** does it not fit your needs.