# How to resize root window size with aspect ratio in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I do (if any user try to resize window width will automatically resize window height too with aspect ratio. That's mean user can't be able to resize only one size. changing one side size will change another side too.)?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523128/resizing-tkinter-frames-with-fixed-aspect-ratio
I think this can help you

Comment: @Sujay ok, I want to make a window as 2:3 size. if root.resizable(width=True, height=True) then the user can able to change only width or only hight or both together. But changing only hight or only width break the window aspect ratio(2:3). Is there any way that if someone drag only window x side to increase width then program will automatically increase height to keeping window aspect ratio same.

Comment: @ArmenGhazaryan I don't want to resize frame. I want to resize window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(After closely reading the comment you made under your question describing how you wanted this to work, I've revised the code once again to make it so.)

You can do it by handling `'<Configure>'` events in an event handler bound to the root window. This is tricky because when you add a binding to the root window, it also gets added to *every* widget it contains — so there's a need to be able to differentiate between them and the root window in the event handler. In the code below this is done by checking to see if the `event.widget.master` attribute is `None`, which indicates the widget being configured is the root window, which doesn't have one.

The code creates the root window and binds root window resizing events to an event handler function that will maintain the desired aspect ratio. When a resize event of the root window is detected, the function checks the aspect ratio of the new size to see if it's has the proper ratio, and when it's doesn't it blocks further processing of the event, and manually sets the window's size to a width and height that does.

```
import tkinter as tk
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 400, 300  # Defines aspect ratio of window.

def maintain_aspect_ratio(event, aspect_ratio):
    """ Event handler to override root window resize events to maintain the
        specified width to height aspect ratio.
    """
    if event.widget.master:  # Not root window?
        return  # Ignore.

    # <Configure> events contain the widget's new width and height in pixels.
    new_aspect_ratio = event.width / event.height

    # Decide which dimension controls.
    if new_aspect_ratio > aspect_ratio:
        # Use width as the controlling dimension.
        desired_width = event.width
        desired_height = int(event.width / aspect_ratio)
    else:
        # Use height as the controlling dimension.
        desired_height = event.height
        desired_width = int(event.height * aspect_ratio)

    # Override if necessary.
    if event.width != desired_width or event.height != desired_height:
        # Manually give it the proper dimensions.
        event.widget.geometry(f'{desired_width}x{desired_height}')
        return "break"  # Block further processing of this event.

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry(f'{WIDTH}x{HEIGHT}')
root.bind('<Configure>', lambda event: maintain_aspect_ratio(event, WIDTH/HEIGHT))
root.mainloop()
```